# Can't Get Applescript To Press Keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, automator

I have been trying to use Applescript in Automator to press certain keys and have looked on countless websites about using Applescript and can't get any answers on how to fix my problem. I am not very good with Applescript but it seems like no matter what I do I can't get anything to work. I am trying to do three things, have one script that just presses the down arrow, one that presses command + O, and one that types "Go". Is anyone able to provide with me with individual scripts that do these things, I am unable to get anything to work and am very frustrated. Side note: I am using Mac OS 10.4

Comment: RE: "Side note: I am using Mac OS 10.4" -- Are you serious about the version number? Version **10.4** was: **Mac OS X Tiger**

Comment: Also - please provide examples of what you have so far, so we can see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Down arrow

```
run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & "keystroke \"\"" & "
end tell"
```

Command + O

```
run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & "keystroke \"o\" using command down" & "
end tell"
```

Go

```
run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & "keystroke \"Go\"" & "
end tell"
```